# React Native bottom tab navigator is too low and cut off at the bottom on iphone 14 pro (real device), expo 46.0.0

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, expo

I'm developing a react native app with expo using createBottomTabNavigator from react-navigation-tabs (react-navigation-tabs version: ^2.4.0, react-navigation version ^4.4.4). When I run my app on any ios simulator (iphone 13, iphone 14 pro, iphone 14 max... with ios 16.2) the bottom tab navigator is displayed correctly. However, on the real device (iphone 14 pro, ios 16.3) the tab bar is moved to the bottom by around 20 pixels and cut off:

[image: Tab bar on real iphone 14 pro]

[image: Tab bar on simulator iphone 14 pro]

When I define the tab navigator I don't change any margin, padding or height properties but stick to the default, the only thing I change is the tint color:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

...

const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: "Home",
                showLabel: false,
                tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
                    return (
                        <Ionicons
                            name={icons.home}
                            size={25}
                            color={tabInfo.tintColor}
                        />
                    );
                },
            },
        },
        Map: {...},
        Workouts: {...},
        Events: {...},
        Profile: {...},
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: colors.primaryColor,
        },
    }
);

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Startup: StartupScreen,
    Auth: AuthNavigator,
    ProfileCreation: ProfileCreationFlowScreen,
    ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Does anyone have an idea why the tab bar is displayed differently on the real iphone 14 pro than on the simulated iphone 14 pro and ideally how to fix this issue on the real device? Any help is appreciated.

Things that I tried out:

- Running the app on differnt simulator devices (iphone 13, iphone 14 pro, iphone 14 max...) -> bottom tab navigator is displayed correctly
- Running the app on a real iphone 11 pro -> bottom tab navigator is displayed correctly
- Running the app on a real iphone 14 pro -> bottom tab navigator is cut off
- Manually increasing the bottom tab navigator's margin in the tab bar options (which worked, but is not a good solution as this differs per device, e.g. margin is too large then for iphone 11 pro...)
- On expo version 44.0.0 the same app used to work and the tab navigator was displayed correctly, after upgrading to expo 46.0.0 the described issue occurred

Answer (score 0):

Try using `safeAreaInsets`

```js
tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.primaryColor,
      safeAreaInsets: {
        bottom: 0,
      },
    },
```

Or

```js
import { getBottomSpace } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';
//...
tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.primaryColor,
      safeAreaInsets: {
        bottom: getBottomSpace(),
      },
    },
```

Comment: Hi Fotios, thanks for your answer, unfortunately, setting the safeAreaInsets.bottom property to 0 on the MainTabNavigator does not solve the problem for me on my iphone 14 pro.

Comment: Try `getBottomSpace` check updated answer.

Comment: safeAreaInsets: {bottom: getBottomSpace()} also does not work, seems like the safeAreaInsets property is completely ignored, I tried different numeric values for bottom as well as 'always' and 'never' (according to documentation). Is there an alternative to setting this property?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that by replacing `getBottomSpace()` from unsupported react-native-iphone-x-helper to `insets.bottom` from react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue by surrounding the content(Whole content inside the App.tsx) with the  component. First, it was like this.

[image: Before adding the component]

After it's like this now

[image: After adding the component]